# Having problems with loops and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I did this simple loop but it doesn't work, do you know why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int array[100], i=0;
do {
        cout<<i<<".";
        cin >> array[i];
        i++;
    }while(array[i] <= 30);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
0.23
1.26
2.27
3.29
4.11
5.17
6.28
7.31
8.17
9.19
10.76
11.54
12.31

Even if I insert a number greater than 30 the loop continues.

Comment: Utterly vital information is needed in order to help you effectively: What was the loop supposed to do?

Comment: Try a debugger. You can single-step the program, look at what's in the variables. Should help you find the problem.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is a very vague description of the symproms at least.

Comment: `array[i]<=30` is a bug. Maybe you wanted `i < 30` but then why did you give the array 100 elements if you only input 30.

Comment: Sit down an discuss the loop logic with [your  Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Focus the conversation on whether or not it's a good idea to read the contents of `array[i]` before storing a value in `array[i]`.

Comment: Why are you comparing for 30?  In ASCII encoding, *printable* characters start at 32.

Comment: The new bug is caused by `i++;` because of that statement the index `i` in `array[i] <= 30` is 1 past the last item read.

Comment: I am now voting to reopen the question, because meanwhile, the OP has clarified the question.

Comment: "Having problems with loops and arrays" is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your loop should look like `for(int i=0;i<=30;i++)` to run 31 times. At the time you enter the loop, `array[i]` contains a value depending on what was allocated on the stack before!

Comment: You're highlighting an important bug and you're probably right, but it's best to hold off on answering until after the asker has made their goals clear. More information could make this answer wrong. Normally the "don't change a question with correct answer" rule will protect the answer, but and at the moment we can't be certain that it's correct.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel true, updated to make it sound less magical.